# How to update div class on radio click with jquery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I got set of `bg-color` in radio buttons:

```
<div class="row mb-2">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">BG Color<br />
   <div class="btn-group">
     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg0" value="bg-primary" />
     <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="ticker_bg0">primary</label>


     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg1" value="bg-secondary" />
     <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="ticker_bg1">secondary</label>


     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg2" value="bg-success" />
     <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="ticker_bg2">success</label>


     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg3" value="bg-danger" />
     <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="ticker_bg3">danger</label>
   </div><!-- btn-group -->
</div><!-- col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 mb-2 -->
```

And this is the text clr `text-color`

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">Text Color<br />
    <div class="btn-group">
     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font1" value="text-dark"  />
     <label class="btn btn-outline-white border-gray-200 text-dark" for="ticker_font1">Dark</label>


     <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font2" value="text-white"  />
     <label class="btn btn-dark" for="ticker_font2">White</label>
    </div>
</div><!-- <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2"> -->
```

And this is the preview div.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">Preview<br />
  <div id="ticker_exp" class="p-2 bg-warning">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" class="text-dark">**ตัวอย่างข้อความวิ่ง**</marquee>
  </div>
</div><!-- <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4"> -->
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
        $("input[name=ticker_bg]").on('change',function(){
            var bgclr=$(this).val();
            $("div#ticker_exp").addClass(bgclr);
            console.log(bgclr);
        });         
        $("input[name=ticker_font]").on('click',function(){
            var txtclr=$(this).val();
            $("marquee").addClass(txtclr);
            console.log(txtclr);
        });
```

The problem is only the `#ticker_bg` working only once. When another click was made. The `#ticker_exp` is not change. The `console.log` shows the radio value very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing for the div is removing the other `bg-` classes.

One approach is store the previous class as `data()` on the div then remove what is stored and store the newly checked value.

As for the text you can use `toggleClass(className, boolean)` to switch between the two

```js
const initalBg = 'bg-warning';
const $div = $("#ticker_exp").data('prev', initalBg)


$("input[name=ticker_bg]").on('change', function() {
  const bgclr = $(this).val(),
        prev = $div.data('prev');
  
  $div.removeClass(prev)
      .addClass(bgclr)
      .data('prev', bgclr);
});

$("input[name=ticker_font]").on('click', function() {
  const isDark = $(this).val() === 'text-dark';
  $("marquee").toggleClass('text-dark', !isDark)
              .toggleClass('text-white', isDark);
});
```

```css
.text-white {
  color: white
}

.text-dark {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">BG Color<br />
      <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg0" value="bg-primary" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="ticker_bg0">primary</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg1" value="bg-secondary" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="ticker_bg1">secondary</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg2" value="bg-success" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="ticker_bg2">success</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg3" value="bg-danger" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="ticker_bg3">danger</label>
      </div>
      <!-- btn-group -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">Text Color<br />
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font1" value="text-dark" />
      <label class="btn btn-outline-white border-gray-200 text-dark" for="ticker_font1">Dark</label>


      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font2" value="text-white" />
      <label class="btn btn-dark" for="ticker_font2">White</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">Preview<br />
    <div id="ticker_exp" class="p-2 bg-warning">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" class="text-dark">**ตัวอย่างข้อความวิ่ง**</marquee>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why I need another `.text-white` and `.text-dark` again when BS5 has it?

Comment: I wasn't sure, haven't used bootstrap for long time and it wasn't changing the color in this demo without the rules. If it works in your page without the rules then just ignore them

Comment: Yeah, I see. So I wonder. But your code is all working anyway!

Comment: Still got some bugs over `marquee` color. The class is not display correctly. The toggle is select the opposite class. I chose `text-white` it's use `text-dark`.

Comment: Switch the booleans then in the toggleClass(). I guess I got confused by the wacky layout in the demo and did them backwards

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working. What is happening behind the scene is, your `$("div#ticker_exp")` is getting added with multiple class each time the radio button is clcked. Since all the classes are setting the background, only one class will get reflected finally. So the fix is to remove all the `bg` classes before trying `$("div#ticker_exp").addClass(bgclr);`. The same applies to `$("marquee").addClass(txtclr);` aswell. Remove all the text color class before adding new.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$("input[name=ticker_bg]").on('change', function () {
  var bgclr = $(this).val();
  $("div#ticker_exp").removeClass();
  
  $("div#ticker_exp").addClass(bgclr);
  console.log(bgclr);
});
$("input[name=ticker_font]").on('click', function () {
  var txtclr = $(this).val();
  $("div#ticker_exp").removeClass();
  $("marquee").addClass(txtclr);
  console.log(txtclr);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">BG Color<br />
      <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg0" value="bg-primary" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="ticker_bg0">primary</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg1" value="bg-secondary" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="ticker_bg1">secondary</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg2" value="bg-success" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="ticker_bg2">success</label>


        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_bg" id="ticker_bg3" value="bg-danger" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="ticker_bg3">danger</label>
      </div><!-- btn-group -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">Text Color<br />
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font1" value="text-dark" />
      <label class="btn btn-outline-white border-gray-200 text-dark" for="ticker_font1">Dark</label>


      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="ticker_font" id="ticker_font2" value="text-white" />
      <label class="btn btn-dark" for="ticker_font2">White</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">Preview<br />
    <div id="ticker_exp" class="p-2 bg-warning">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" class="text-dark">**ตัวอย่างข้อความวิ่ง**</marquee>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("div#ticker_exp").removeClass()` will remove the `p-2` class also